# Erlang regex to match either the end of a line, or the end of the file

Tags: regex, erlang

I've tried [\n$] and a few other things, but none seem to work in Erlang (even if they work on regexr).  What's the right way to do this in Erlang (re:compile)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `(\n|$)`:

```
> re:run("foobar", "(\n|$)").
{match,[{6,0},{6,0}]}
> re:run("foo\nbar", "(\n|$)").
{match,[{3,1},{3,1}]}
```

That is, there are two alternatives: either match a newline, or the end of the string.

Comment: The \n doesn't need escaped (\\n) ?

Comment: It works either way. With one backslash, `\n` turns into a literal newline in the regular expression, which in turn matches the newline in the string.  But `\n` is also a special regexp pattern that matches newlines, so writing `\\n` in your regular expression would achieve the same thing.